# How do I efficiently search through an ordered list?

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, search

I have a function that predicts a words being typed and returns the possibilities in an array. Unfortunately those aren’t sorted by frequency used. So I have a list of 10K ordered words listed by most frequent to less frequent. What would be an efficient way to compare the words in the array and the ordered list to return the most frequent one? (i.e the one it encounters first?)

I was tipped off by a friend to use a binary search tree but I really don't see how that helps me. From what I understood from the [following website](http://waynewbishop.com/swift/binary-search-trees), only numerical values can be used.. Am I wrong in thinking so? Is there a better way of doing the aforementioned task?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could create a dictionary with words as keys and frequencies as values. Then iterate over your result array, use the dictionary to obtain the frequency value for each item, and predict the item with the highest frequency.

I wouldn't use a vanilla binary search tree here. It would be possible - as Taylor Kirkpatrick says, you could just create a tree with words as keys and frequencies and use that to find the frequency for each result word, in much the same way as the dictionary solution.

The problem is that you cannot guarantee that  a simple binary tree will be balanced. From the sound of it your data would probably be OK, since your words are in frequency order. The worst case would be if the words were in alphabetic order - then your binary tree would end up being identical to a linked list - it would never branch, since every node would attach to the right of the previous one. So the computational complexity of a search would be the same as iterating over the array of words - O(n) instead of O(log2N) (which is the best case for binary trees).

Of course, you could guard against this by randomising the list of words before doing the insert. But to my mind it's just easier to use a dictionary.  I don't know what the actual implementation of Swift dictionaries is (and we won't until they open source it in a couple of months), but you can take it as read that it will out perform a vanilla BT for value retrieval.

I don't know what the background to this problem is - if you are learning CS it might be worth implementing the BST just for intellectual growth - in this case, with only 10,000 items you might find the performance differences are ultimately quite small. But if you are a working programmer trying to solve a problem, go with the dictionary approach.

Answer (score 1):

You put all your words into a dictionary or a set. That's it. Dictionary if you have data associated with the words, set if you have no data and just want to know if the word is in the list or not.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Put your word list into it. For every character entered, you traverse the Trie as deeply as you can and then show all paths to leaf nodes as possible completions.

Since the world like you have is likely static, you can precompute the Trie and load from disk/network/whatever at startup if performance is a concern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a binary search tree with anything as the actual value. To actually make use of the tree, use the frequency of the words as the numerical value. This is actually a pretty good solution to your problem. Each node of the tree will contain this word and a numeric value that represents the frequency of the word.

[Here are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538598/word-frequency-in-a-binary-search-tree-in-c) [a few](http://computersciencetopics.com/a-binary-tree-assignment-create-a-frequency-list-of-words-in-a-passage) [links](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse326/02wi/homework/326hw5.htm) to help you out with making it.

Hope that helps.